# Black Hole Singularity Other Universe

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities, wormholes, multiverse

It is thought that there is another universe beyond the singularities of black holes. Is it because width of the light cones become zero at the singularity, meaning that you can cross infinite distance in a moment?

Also, is it the same 'other universe' as the regions 3 and 4 (white hole) of the Kruskal Diagrams? In that diagram region 4 seems not connected to r = 0 line of region 2 (singularity), and we seem to travel directly from 1 to 3 without ever encountaring any singularity if we travel at FTL speed. In short, is the hypothetical other universe behind the singularity same as the one in an Einstein Rosen Bridge?

Comment: "It is thought that there is another universe beyond the singularities of black holes." By whom?

Comment: Like this article. And many others.https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/100409-black-holes-alternate-universe-multiverse-einstein-wormholes

Comment: It is thought so by virtually no one in physics, only in pop culture.

Comment: That's what I am curious about. I don’t think National Geographic utterly lied unless some scientists also think the same. Let others answer if you can't.

Comment: Hell no! We know exactly what happens beyond the horizon thanks to General Relativity.

Comment: "We know exactly what happens beyond the horizon thanks to General Relativity. "   That is not correct, GR is very successful where we can make measurements and observations, but we cannot measure or observe behind the horizon of a black hole.  Before data showed us wrong physicists believed that classical mechanics and classical electrodynamics explained everything in the world and only engineering remained. The experiments in the microcosm of atoms proved that those theories were not enough, and quantum mechanics had to be invented to fit the data. Maybe in the future new observations from

Comment: black holes might show that GR is not enough.

Comment: @Nayeem1 Let us be clear: no one knows what lies beyond the event horizon. The schwarzschild solution in a vacuum can be thought of as a "continuation of the curve" but this by no mean show that, for example, the light cones really flip at 90°, nor that the tetrads goes complex-valued in certain charts.

Comment: Well, here we are not talking about whether GR is enough or not. We assume it true, and discuss its predictions beyond the horizon.

Comment: Looks like GR does make some predictions about Einstein Rosen Bridges and white holes being connected to black holes leading to other universes. Therefore my question still remains a valid one.

Comment: The most complete model based on an Einstein-Rosen bridge may be Nikodem Poplawski's torsion-based cosmology, described in many 2009-2021 preprints found by his name on Cornell University's << Arxiv >> website:  However, it "avoids" any singularity, rather than going through one.  Also, it uses 1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory (which assigns a tiny spatial extent to fermions), rather than 1915's General Relativity, so I'm suggesting you replace the GR tag with a "cosmology" tag.  (PSE doesn't currently have an ECT tag.)

Comment: The suggested edit might also bring out some info about Bojowald's QM-inclusive "bouncing" model, with which I'm less familiar.

Comment: I've put a further comment under the 2nd of the related questions, which might also make Einstein's collaboration with Cartan clearer to the OP.